# How to enable inline (sandboxed) groovy scripts?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to use this sample script query:

```
POST /_search
{
    "script_fields": {
        "my_field": {
            "script": "1 + my_evar",
            "params": {
              "my_evar": 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which results in the following error message:

> "reason": "scripts of type [inline], operation [search] and lang [groovy] are disabled"

I've tried to enable scripting with this bit of elasticsearch.yml configuration:

```
script.inline: true
script.indexed: true
script.search: true
script.update: true
script.mapping: true
script.groovy.sandbox.enabled: true
```

Am I missing a setting?

Comment: Have had enough pain with Painless, huh? Welcome to the club.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting the the following in **elasticsearch.yml** worked for me.

```
script.engine.groovy.inline.search: on
```

Comment: `script.engine.groovy.inline.update: on` is also useful. Full docs here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-security.html

Answer (score 4):

thanks @Richa, I actually tried that but I got this error

> script.disable_dynamic is not a supported setting, replace with fine-grained script settings.
>   Dynamic scripts can be enabled for all languages and all operations by replacing `script.disable_dynamic: false` with `script.inline: on` and `script.indexed: on`

So then I tried just these three settings and it worked fine.

Comment: Thank you. I just put the 2 lines  "script.inline: on" and "script.indexed: on" in my elasticsearch.yml file and It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Use this settings:

```
script.disable_dynamic: false
```